# XNA: Rotate a model to face a target

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

What rotation Matrix can I use to get my Model face a certain point?

My model is a character, and I want it to face the camera position.

I tried Matrix.LookAt, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Define `doesn't work`

Comment: My model just disappear, after some research I found Matrix.LookAt is only used for the `view` for camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that `lookVector` is the vector in model space that defines the view direction of the character. Usually this is one of the principal axes (e.g. the z-axis). Let's further assume that the character is positioned at `characterPosition` and that the target point is `target`.

The view direction towards the target in world space is

```
var view = target - characterPosition;
```

Now all we need to do is find a rotation matrix that maps `lookVector` to `view`. The solution is not unique, but we are looking for the solution with a minimal rotation angle.

The rotation axis can be found with the cross product, the rotation angle with the dot product:

```
var rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross(lookVector, view);
var rotationAngle = (float)Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(lookVector, view) / lookVector.Length() / view.Length());
```

Now we can construct the rotation matrix:

```
var rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(rotationAxis, rotationAngle);
```

Answer (score 0):

**NO Wait!  Matrix.CreateLookAt Works!**

Think you have only used something like `Matrix.CreateLookAt(Ship.Position, Target.Position, Ship.ModelRotation.Up)`

But you have to add a `Matrix.CreateTranslation` to get it work. Or it will change it's shape instead of rotation!

This is the code

```
Ship.ModelRotation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Ship.Position) * Matrix.CreateLookAt(Ship.Position, Target.Position, Ship.ModelRotation.Up)
```

I was in a serious trouble with this in two days. But this stupid code sloved that

**Edit:**

I don't know why, but this is the code working for me currently

```
Ship.ModelRotation = Matrix.invert( Matrix.CreateTranslation(Ship.Position) * Matrix.CreateLookAt(Ship.Position, Target.Position, Ship.ModelRotation.Up))
```

**Note - This is a Visual basic code; Think you could just make it into C#**